# How to find if the email app is present on the device on Android API 30?

Tags: android

My app requires to check if an email app is present so we can hide a button for sending the email.

On API 30, Android has made change to the package manager so we cannot access the activities anymore, unless they have been declared in the `<queries>` tag.

I have setup the queries node on the AndroidManifest file as follows

```
 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

When I try to query using the the intent, the method on the package manager returns zero items.

```
 fun isEmailAppInstalled(context: Context): Boolean {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
        return context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).isNotEmpty()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the new documentation based on API level 30 or higher , if you want to access other apps installed on device you have to declare package visibility by adding the `<queries>` element in your app's manifest file. What you are doing here. And same time the system makes some apps visible to your app automatically. We can check by

```
adb shell dumpsys package queries
```

In the command output, find the forceQueryable section. This section includes the list of packages that the device has made visible to your app automatically.(this part copied from documentation).

[image]

So in this case without `<queries>` tag I can access Email app from my device on API 30 and also 29 by [Intent.createChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
  fun isEmailAppInstalled(context: Context) {
    /* val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
    return context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).isNotEmpty()*/
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose your Email App"))
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Log.i("ZI", "No Email App Found")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In your `AndroidManifest` add:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
```

And alter your code to

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        return context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).isNotEmpty()
```

Language syntax may need double chekcing/updating as I have tested the solution in `Xamarin.Forms` and is back compat with API 29 and below too.

Comment: Worked for me in Android application.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email):

```
fun composeEmail(addresses: Array<String>, subject: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("mailto:")    //<- only email apps should handle this
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    }

    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```